# Thumb return by YouTube API Player getClickToPlayButton() function is not playing video onclick

Tags: youtube-api

DisplayObject return by getClickToPlayButton() function of YouTube API is not playing video now.

I am using Chrome-less YouTube API player with custom chrome. My YouTube Playlist app is different SWF which load the custom chrome player swf and use YT object to create thumbs getClickToPlayButton().

I have also tried it on single SWF only using YouTube chromeless player and simple provided thumb by getClickToPlayButton() function but it does not play the video on thumb click.

Comment: An almost 12 months old development just broke today that uses getClickToPlayButton(). Indeed, the thumb is there, but nothing happens but the thumb disappearing (no loading icon, no video, no sound, nothing) Think either Google/Youtube broke something regarding this method, or they just modified its behaviour and we won't have a clue until they update the API documentation... I'm currently far from my office, thus I can't investigate, so if anyone knows or learns something about this issue, please help us! :-)

Comment: Please see https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4239